# Short story about time traveller who brings virus from future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

A short story about a time traveller from the future who brings a virus to cull the human race in our present. He muses on previous unsuccessful attempts and why more direct action is needed. He tries to give a woman pills that can save her but she is unconvinced by his story. He sees her throw the pills away as she walks off.

Can't remember when I read it or where.

Comment: So did he bring a virus from the future or a cure for a virus, or both?

Comment: A short story about a time traveller from the future who brings a virus to cull the human race in our present. He tries to give a woman pills that can save her but she is unconvinced by his story. So, both.