# A short story about time traveller who brings virus from future

Tags: story-identification

At the start of the story, the main character says that when you arrive at your destination after time travel, don't come tumbling out of a broom closet, that if you appear on the street already walking, it's much less conspicuous. The character has brought a disease from the future to cull the human race. He said that opportunities had been given to the human race to limit their numbers but the population keeps growing. He interacts with a contemporary woman and offers her the cure to the upcoming plague. Some people get the cure so that humanity doesn’t totally get wiped out. He must have told her something of the looming catastrophe but she is skeptical and throws the cure away.

Read during the 80s or 90s in a short-story collection.

Comment: Just to keep them tied together, it's believed to maybe be the same story as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217512/short-story-about-time-traveller-who-brings-virus-from-future, but that's not certain.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I suspect these are the same user. Note that both have identical info about the story and both have very similar names.

Comment: @Valorum: On the other hand, he posted another question (now deleted) that was a link to the other one and a message along the lines of "I'd also like to know the answer to this".

Comment: @Roysto: If you did accidentally create two accounts [here are the instructions to merge them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: It's possible I did that, my memory can be cloudy at times. Thanks for the 'structions.